# No IPs in the GKE ca.cert which results in SSL errors while connection to the API server

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I looked into the service account ca.crt files that get deployed into the container and they don't contain any SAN with the IP or dns name of the master nodes. This results in SSL errors like: https://0.0.0.0:10250/metrics: x509: cannot validate certificate for 0.0.0.0 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs.

Did anybody else run into this problem? How did you solve it other then allowing insecure ssl?

Answer (score 2):

The ca cert provided by a service account (`/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt`) is for communicating with the apiserver (served by the master on GKE).

```
# curl --cacert /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt https://kubernetes -H "Authorization: Bearer $(cat /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)"
{
  "paths": [
    "/api",
    ...
  ]
```

It looks like you are trying to talk to the kubelet API (port 10250). The kubelet API serves a self-signed cert, so insecure is the only way.

Comment: I understand the purpose of this certificate but even with self signed certs it is possible to add SAN in order to make them usable. My current problem are the missing SAN regardless if they are self signed or not.I tried to run a prometheus instance that scrapes the api server but I got error I described in the question.

Comment: I might not be understanding fully then. It looks like you are trying to hit the kubelet API (port 10250). If you are trying to hit the kubelet on the GKE master, that is not possible. If you are trying to hit the kubelet on your node, the ca cert in the service account is not useful.

Comment: I try to hit the kubelet API on my GKE node. It looks like the cert for the kubelet API does not share the same ca as the API-Server.Is there a way to get access to the used CA cert or add my own CA cert with GKE? What is your recommendation if I want to access the kubelet API on GKE using secure SSL?

Comment: The kubelet API serves a self-signed cert, so there's no CA to trust. The "insecure" piece here is that you are accepting a server cert w/o having a CA chain that vouches for it (to prevent man-in-the-middle). If you're contacting the kubelet API from a pod running on that node, it's not too bad of a problem, because the only MITM you'd be worried about is local. If you're going across your GCE private network, then you might be worried about somebody w/ admin access to your project MITMing you.